# SIP SUBSCRIBE requests fail

Tags: nat, sip

I have the problem, that my client can login with a password and call out, but does not receive calls. When i troubleshoot it via tcpdump, it tells me, that `REGISTER` works, but `SUBSCRIBE` does not.

```
21:11:24.734317 IP router.48299 > fritz.box.sip: SIP: REGISTER sip:fritz.box SIP/2.0
21:11:24.739130 IP router.box.sip > router.48299: SIP: SIP/2.0 200 OK
21:11:24.769070 IP router.48299 > fritz.box.sip: SIP: SUBSCRIBE sip:myphone@fritz.box SIP/2.0
21:11:24.772725 IP router.box.sip > router.48299: SIP: SIP/2.0 401 Unauthorized
```

Client: sipdroid (reachable via wlan0)
Server: A Fritzbox (reachable via eth0)
Router: A Banana Pi

In between: a router, which `MASQUERADE`s the traffic:

```
-A POSTROUTING -o wlan0 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p udp --dport 5060 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 5060 -j MASQUERADE
-A POSTROUTING -o eth0 -p tcp --dport 5061 -j MASQUERADE
-A FORWARD -j ACCEPT
```

The strange thing is, that the problem seems to be that the voip server denies the `SUBSCRIBE` request, while the login works with the `REGISTER` command.

Comment: 401 is authorization request, not failure yet. Client may use nonce counter to send credential with each REGISTER but skip this for SUBSCRIBE, hard to say. You may try other client, but SUBSCRIBE (would it be solicited MWI?) is not essential for the calls. You may try to reduce registration expiration to 60s or so to reduce the chance of NAT problems.

Answer (score 0):

You will need to do some packet captures to find out what's actually inside your SIP packets. Without knowing anything more about how your SIP is configured (is it a trunk?), chances are it is trying to issue a `SUBSCRIBE` with the IP address of the internal client which the upstream SIP server is rejecting.

Running SIP behind NAT is notoriously difficult, so much so that there are many SIP-aware gateways. I do not know if the routing software you are running on your Pi is doing anything here.

I would investigate if your SIP client supports STUN (Session Traversal Utilities for NAT). If it does, configuring it to query an external STUN server before initating any SIP sessions might be the way to go.

Comment: It's just a masquerading nat, with conntrack module for sip loaded. The client has STUN disabled, as it's not useful in the LAN. The Pi serves a wifi, which is separated from the home network, but should route for specific clients the connection to the SIP server of the DSL router. What is needed for SIP to work? I would like to have some masquerading and/or DNAT to a single server.